# How to slow down text to Speech with SSML - voice sounds distorted/warped/ghastly

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, voice, slowdown, ssml

i am using **nuance dragon mobile sdk** for iPhone, for using text to speech.
The readed text is a little bit to fast and i want to make it slower, so the user can **learn** the words. My aim is to slow down the text a bit. That works very fine with SSML and prosody tag, see this code:

```
<prosody rate="slow">This is the text which is spoken slow,
but the voice sounds distorted/warped/ghastly</prosody>
```

The voice sounds **distorted, warped and ghastly**.
Do you understand what i mean?
What can i do to get a **clear voice** but **slow speaked text**?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without "nuance dragon mobile sdk"? It appears that SSML is not supported by AVSpeechSynthesizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

taken from  here: http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.2.4

```
rate: a change in the speaking rate for the contained text. Legal values are: 
a relative change or "x-slow", "slow", "medium", "fast", "x-fast", or "default". 
Labels "x-slow" through "x-fast" represent a sequence of monotonically non-decreasing
speaking rates. When a number is used to specify a relative change it acts as a 
multiplier of the default rate. For example, a value of 1 means no change in speaking 
rate, a value of 2 means a speaking rate twice the default rate, and a value of 0.5 
means a speaking rate of half the default rate. The default rate for a voice depends on 
the language and dialect and on the personality of the voice. The default rate for a 
voice should be such that it is experienced as a normal speaking rate for the voice when 
reading aloud text. Since voices are processor-specific, the default rate will be as 
well.
```