# how to use Speech Synthesis Markup Language?

Tags: html

I want to create web base text to speech app.
i am using this code but nothing happen plz help me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE speak PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SYNTHESIS 1.0//EN"
                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/synthesis.dtd">
<speak version="1.0"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis
                   http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/synthesis.xsd"
       xml:lang="en-US">
  <p>
    <s>You have 4 new messages.</s>
    <s>The first is from Stephanie Williams and arrived at <break/> 3:45pm.
    </s>
    <s>
      The subject is <prosody rate="-20%">ski trip</prosody>
    </s>

  </p>
</speak>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a platform which supports SSML, such as:

- FreeTTS/Java Web Start
- Windows/SAPI
- Windows Phone 8
- iOS
- An ePub3 reader

**References**

- [Speech for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206958)
- [Producing Speech Output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684753.aspx)
- [epub3: SSML Attributes](http://epub-revision.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build/301/spec/epub-contentdocs.html#sec-xhtml-ssml-attrib)
- [Using FreeTTS in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753936/1113772)
- [SSML using Chrome TTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635653/1113772)
- [How to slow down text to Speech with SSML - voice sounds distorted/warped/ghastly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297963/1113772)